# Как работает перемножение матриц?

Tags: opengl, матрицы

Вот два кода.

```
glm::mat4 proj = glm::ortho ( 0.0, 1920.0, 0.0, 1080.0, -1.0, 1.0 );
glm::mat4 view = glm::translate ( glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3 ( 2.0, 3.0f, 2.0f ) );
glm::mat4 result = proj * view;
```

Вот какой вывод.

```
  0.001042  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  0.000000  0.001852  0.000000  0.000000
  0.000000  0.000000 -1.000000  0.000000
 -1.000000 -1.000000 -0.000000  1.000000

  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000
  2.000000  3.000000  2.000000  1.000000
========================================
  0.001042  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  0.000000  0.001852  0.000000  0.000000
  0.000000  0.000000 -1.000000  0.000000
 -0.997917 -0.994444 -2.000000  1.000000
```

Как вот эти числа, -0.997917 и -0.994444, как они вычисляются?
Как они там перемножаются? Вот например из 2 становить -2, но как? А в glm всё ищу, но не найду, ищу operator* для mat4.

Comment: первый блок кода где 0.001042 это матрица ortho, второй блок матрицы, это translate. Третий блок, это перемножение чего то.

Comment: Так это же обычное умножение матриц. Попробуйте погуглить его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Умножение матриц для чайников**

<sub>**Небольшая справка:**</sub>

Так же, как умножение обычных чисел, умножение матриц *ассоциативно*, т.е.
`(a * b) * c  ==  a * (b * c)`.

Но, в отличие от умножения чисел, умножение матриц не *коммутативно*, т.е.
`a * b  !=  b * a`.

Чтобы две матрицы можно было умножить, ширина первой матрицы должна совпадать с высотой второй матрицы.

Матрица, которая получится в результате, по высоте совпадает с первой матрицей, а по ширине - со второй.

<sub>**Как считать:**</sub>

Каждая ячейка в новой матрице вычисляется так:

```
c[x][y] = a[0][y] * b[x][0] + a[1][y] * b[x][1] + ... + a[n-1][y] * b[x][n-1];
```

<sup>Где: `a` - первая матрица, `b` - вторая матрица, `c` - результат, `n` - одновременно ширина первой матрицы и высота второй.

Предполагается, что `[0][0]` - это верхний-левый угол матрицы. Первая скобка - это `x`, вторая - `y`.</sup>

Если нужно это запрограммировать, то самый простой способ - три вложенных `for`: Два для того, чтобы пройти по всем ячейкам новой матрицы, и третий, чтобы просуммировать для этой ячейки `n` произведений.